# Saving a remote image from facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, http, laravel, intervention

Any idea what's wrong?
I end up with 1bytes files and they are wrong. Using Intervention Image & PHP. Tried many ways to get it but nothing... If I just want to display it works but I can't save the picture...

```
$avatar_url     = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' . $id . '/picture?type=square&width=140&height=140&redirect=false';
                    $avatar_pic_url = json_decode(file_get_contents($avatar_url), true)['data']['url'];
                    dd($avatar_pic_url);
                    $avatar         = Image::make($avatar_pic_url);
                    $extension      = 'jpg';
                    // save it
                    $destinationPath        = 'uploads/avatars/';
                    $filename               = uniqid(). '.' . $extension;
                    $path_to_temp_image     = $avatar->dirname . '/' . $avatar->filename;
                    $key                    = $destinationPath . $filename;
                    // Upload avatar to remote storage
                    $uploadSuccess = Storage::put($key, $path_to_temp_image);
```

Comment: Missing semicolon on the second line. Open the file up with something like notepad++ and see if there's a php error printed inside.

Comment: Thanks. Was a typo when bringing it in here through

Comment: Did you set allow_url_fopen to on? Is the user whose picture you're trying to see have settings set to private? It looks like there's a newer version of the api (v2.4). Did read if you had to use the latest version or not. That's all I got.

Comment: Thanks, so I read 2.4 docs. Picture not private. What is the allow_url_fopen? That might be it...

Comment: It's a php method. Check php.net/allow_url_fopen. You need to tell the server to open urls. By default it won't for security reasons.

Comment: @commandantp I think that your problem might be here `$avatar         = Image::make($avatar_url);`, shouldn't it be `$avatar         = Image::make($avatar_pic_url);`? also, what does `dd` function do?

Comment: @godvsdeity did try both doesn't matter. I will look into the allow_url_fopen and get back!

Comment: @commandantp hmm, are you running this code with `dd` function into it? because according to `dd` documentation it ends the execution of the script? `allow_url_fopen` is enabled by default, anyway you can still check it if you want to make sure

Comment: I used the dd just for quick test to avoid the whole thing to run. I put it after the saving part too but image saved was 1byte - so same. Will try url fopen..

Comment: @Terminus looks like my allow_url_fopen is already 'on' .... :-(

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is test it in the browser and see what happens. Try with and without the `redirect=false`. Good luck.

Comment: @terminus tried earlier. I see the image after being redirected to the URL . if I try to fetch tmwithout the redirect false it just won't work. intriguing...